# Where to define what locales to generate in centos7?

Tags: centos, locale

I'm building a minimal image for netbooting for centos7 so every byte counts. But the default /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive is 100+MB big.

I can generate a trimmed down version of the file using localedef resuling in just 1.6MB. But every time glibc-common is updated in the chroot used to generate the netboot image the locale-archive is rebuilt.

Where do I configure what locales should be included in locale-archive by default?